# Xcode 4 changing view help

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Does anyone know a simple way to change views on xcode 4 as for a school project me and a team have desided to atempt to make a iphone app tourist guide for our town consisting of 100+ pages but none of us have any codeing exsperiance and all tutorials found so far do not work with xcode 4. All we need is a quick reuseable way to link pages with buttons so if anyone has a good begginer guide for xcode 4 can you please post it.

Thanks Sam

Answer (score 0):

This may seem tongue-in-cheek but really isn't: Make a website.

If none of you have *any* coding experience and this is a school project, that's the easiest way. It's also cross-platform, easily updatable, and if you were just presentng static content anyway, you don't really need a native app.